# How to install scikit-image package on Canopy-64bit?

Tags: canopy, scikit-image

I am running on Window 7 and I would like to install the Scikit-image package on my Canopy 64-bit. I have looked up the Available-packeges in the package-Manager of Canopy and the scikit-image is included but the only option I have is to click on subscribe. If I click on that the ENTHOUGHT web page pops up offering me to download Canopy-express (the only that is free) but (I guess) I already have that. Is there a way to download only the package that I need? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observe, scikit-image is provided pre-built only to subscribers (paid or academic), i.e. not in Canopy Express. If you have Visual Studio 2008 on your system, you can build it yourself, following these general guidelines:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

Also, please note the following quirks regarding this package's naming:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22447950-Scikit-learn-and-Scikit-image-naming-conventions

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when installing  Scikit-image. Canopy is installed but not really helping.

Actually there are installation guides on the page http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html.

The Build Requirements are:

```
Python >= 2.6
Numpy >= 1.6
Cython >= 0.19.2
Six >=1.3
```

And the Runtime requirements are:

```
SciPy
Matplotlib
NetworkX
Pillow (or PIL)
```

I had them all installed before I installed scikit-image.

There are maybe other small accessory packages required when you installing above major ones. But there isn't a problem.

Another thing I paid attention to is to ensure the installed scikit-image versions were uninstalled before taking above ones installed 1 by 1. And you may need to exit Python IDLE.

Last, if you are a Windows user, I would recommend downloads from PyPi and http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Good luck.